# Phyton me da error al tratar de guardar el resultado de una funcion en una variable

Tags: python

estoy aprendiendo Python y tengo un problema al tratar de hacer un programa sencillo, al tratar de ejecutar el programa me tira el siguiente problema, quisiera saber si alguien me podría ayudar ya que he intentado y no se si es problema de la versión de Python o que pueda ser.

**Código**

```py
def calculadora(valor):
    mex_to_col_rate = 185,56
    return mex_to_col_rate * valor

def run():
    print("C A L C U L A D O R A  D E  D I V I S A S")
    print("convertir pesos mexicanos a pesos colombianos")
    print("")

    valor = float(input('Ingrese el valor de pesos mexicanos a pesos colombianos') #linea 17

    resultados= calculadora(valor)

    print('${} pesos mexicanos son ${} pesos colombianos'.format(valor,resultado))
    print('')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

**Error**

```
PS C:\\Users\Sebas\Phyton\Calculadora.py> & C:\\Users\Sebas\AppData\Local/Programs\Python\Python39\\python.exe c:\\Users\Sebas\Phyton\Calculadora.py
  File "c:\\Users\Sebas\Phyton\Calculadora.py", line 17
    resultado = calculadora(valor)
    ^
  SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow, te invito a hacer el [tour]. Por favor, [no publiques imágenes con código fuente](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2869/21), copia y pega directamente el código en tu pregunta. NO olvides incluir de la misma manera mensajes exactos de error. Un saludo.

Comment: Te falta cerrar un paréntesis en la línea 17. Y el código que has pegado no es exactamente el mismo que estás usando, pues tu código asigna `valor = calculadora(valor)`, mientras que el error mostrado está asignando a `resultado`.

Comment: Por cierto que este tipo de errores van a mejorar mucho con el próximo Python3.10, ya que en vez de un simple "syntax error" en la línea siguiente, te va a señalar el error en la línea en que olvidaste cerrar paréntesis, junto con un consejo amigable del estilo "quizás olvidaste una coma?", o bien "La { no ha sido cerrada", o bien "Faltan : al final de la línea"

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que veo el valor que asignas al *peso mexicano* en equivalencia al *peso colombiano* es de `185,56` esto en expresión decimal, sin embargo *python* no reconoce los decimales por una coma *`,`* sino por un punto *`.`* al igual que las calculadoras de un dispositivo movil (en los mas modernos especialmente), sin embargo el error que te devuelve es diferente al que deberia retornar `TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'`

Python utiliza la coma *`,`* para separar valores por lo que tu variable contiene 2 valores uno es el `185` y otro es el `56`, podrás darte cuenta al hacer esto en tu función:

```py
def calculadora(valor):
    valor, otro = 185,56
    print(f'el primer valor:{valor}\n segundo:{otro}')
#el primer valor:185
# segundo:56
```

En cuanto a tu error, gracias a mis *ojos divinos* me di cuenta que te falta un paréntesis `)` **:/**

```py
float(input("Ingrese el valor de pesos mexicanos a pesos colombiano") #aqui falta cerrar la conversión de float
resultado = calculadora(valor) # por lo que esta sintaxis es invalida
```

Al faltar un paréntesis python sigue interpretando todo y al haber un salto de linea en la función `float()` genera el error, parte que la función `float()` no recibe como otra función como segundo parámetro.
Solo cambia lo que te digo y el error debería estor resuelto. :)

Comment: Gracias por la correcion, pero de todos modos me sigue saliendo el fallo de la linea 17 cuando asigno lo que retorna la funcion a la variable, no sabes que mas podria ser?

Comment: edite mi respuesta, mirala

Comment: Muchas gracias men, me sirvio, gracias

Comment: @jachguate bueno, igual gracias por todo, que tengas buen día:)

Comment: Procedo a borrar los comentarios. Un cordial saludo Christian :)